# I am using Azure Devops to build and push my Docker image. How can I pass arguments while doing buildAndPush using Docker task?

Tags: docker, azure-devops, continuous-integration

I have created a pipeline to build a Docker image and push it to my container registry. I am using Docker task for doing this (buildAndPush command). Here is a YAML snippet of the 'Build and Push' step:

```
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build and Push
  inputs:
    command: buildAndPush
    containerRegistry: dockerRegistryServiceConnection1
    repository: contosoRepository
    tags: latest
    arguments: --label buildtype=nightly
```

The `arguments` input is ignored by the task. How can I pass arguments to the Docker command?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

When using `buildAndPush` command in Docker task, the `arguments` are ignored. Since this is a combination of two Docker commands, the `arguments` input becomes ambiguous.

If you want to add some arguments to your build command, you can split build and push into two separate steps like this:

```
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build
  inputs:
    command: build
    containerRegistry: dockerRegistryServiceConnection1
    repository: contosoRepository
    tags: latest
    arguments: --label buildtype=nightly

- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Push
  inputs:
    command: push
    containerRegistry: dockerRegistryServiceConnection1
    repository: contosoRepository
    tags: latest
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: couldn't they have `buildArguments` and `pushArguments`?

Comment: Do we have delete image task as well

Comment: For arguments I used `arguments: '--build-arg FEED_ACCESSTOKEN=$(VSS_NUGET_ACCESSTOKEN)'`  and it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

buildandpush will ignore the 'arguments' you are passing as mentioned in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/docker-v2?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=yaml#other-commands-and-arguments) and @Anjikya's answer.

[image]

I want to mention one additional point about the argument we are passing (since I spent few hours on passing the arguments in the right way).

**Passing the arguments the right way**

You can pass multiple variables in the yaml by using

```
--build-arg FEED_ACCESSTOKEN=$(NugetFeedPatToken) --build-arg arg2='somedumyvariable'
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#build-arg

```
- task: Docker@2
    displayName: Docker Build
    inputs:
      containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
      repository: $(imageRepository)
      command: build
      dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
      buildContext: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/src/'
      arguments: '--build-arg FEED_ACCESSTOKEN=$(NugetFeedPatToken) --build-arg arg2='somedumyvariable'
      tags: |
          $(tag)
```