# How to substitute environment variables in Nuget.config when creating a Docker container via Azure Devops YAML Pipelines?

Tags: .net-core, dockerfile, nuget, azure-pipelines

I am creating a .NET Core 6 web app inside a docker container via Azure Devops YAML pipelines.

However I am having problems with nuget not restoring packages from a private commercial external nuget feed (for Telerik). "HTTP401 failed authentication" response.

So how do I pass in in the values for the %TELERIKUSERNAME% and %TELERIKPASSWORD% environmental variables from the build pipeline to docker?

The MS Docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops say `arguments` gets ignored (even if I knew the format to use)

FYI I am retrieving the values securely from Azure Keyvault, converting them to Environment variables via powershell and passing them into a different .net core nuget restore task (not shown). This part of the pipelines is working correctly, so I know I have the correct credentials.

I think this is all the necessary files I need to share for my current problem

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["A/A.csproj", "A/"]
COPY ["B/B.csproj", "B/"]
COPY ["C/C.csproj", "C/"]
COPY ["D/D.csproj", "D/"]
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/A"
RUN dotnet build "A.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "A.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "A.dll"]
```

Nuget.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
        <add key="Telerik_NuGet" value="https://nuget.telerik.com/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    </packageSources>   
    <packageSourceCredentials>
        <Telerik_NuGet>
            <add key="Username" value="%TELERIKUSERNAME%" />
            <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="%TELERIKPASSWORD%" />
        </Telerik_NuGet>
    </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

azure-pipelines.yml

```
# ... snip...

- task: Docker@2
      displayName: Create Docker Image
      inputs:
        containerRegistry: $(DockerContainerRegistryConnection)
        repository: $(DockerRepository)
        command: 'buildAndPush'
        addPipelineData: true
        tags: $(Build.BuildNumber)
        Dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'
        buildContext: 'src/'
```

Cheers

kyle

Answer (score 4):

Managed to resolve this finally. Following advice on these pages:

1. https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/documentation/scenarios/nuget-credentials.md
2. [I am using Azure Devops to build and push my Docker image. How can I pass arguments while doing buildAndPush using Docker task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60287354/i-am-using-azure-devops-to-build-and-push-my-docker-image-how-can-i-pass-argume)

Basically creating Docker `Arg`s that are temporary and dont get saved inside the container for security reasons as they arent the last "layer" within the container. Also split the TML task into two.

Changed my files to be:

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build

ARG TELERIKUSERNAME
ARG TELERIKPASSWORD

WORKDIR /src
COPY ["A/A.csproj", "A/"]
COPY ["B/B.csproj", "B/"]
COPY ["C/C.csproj", "C/"]
COPY ["D/D.csproj", "D/"]
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/A"
RUN dotnet build "A.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "A.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "A.dll"]
```

Nuget.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
        <add key="Telerik_NuGet" value="https://nuget.telerik.com/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    </packageSources>   
    <packageSourceCredentials>
        <Telerik_NuGet>
            <add key="Username" value="%TELERIKUSERNAME%" />
            <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="%TELERIKPASSWORD%" />
        </Telerik_NuGet>
    </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

azure-pipelines.yml

```
# ... snip ...

    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build Docker Image
      inputs:
        command: build
        containerRegistry: $(DockerContainerRegistryConnection)
        repository: $(DockerRepository)
        tags: $(Build.BuildNumber)
        arguments: '--build-arg TELERIKUSERNAME=$(TELERIKUSERNAME) --build-arg TELERIKPASSWORD=$(TELERIKPASSWORD)'
        buildContext: 'src/'

    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Push Docker Image
      inputs:
        command: push
        containerRegistry: $(DockerContainerRegistryConnection)
        repository: $(DockerRepository)
        tags: $(Build.BuildNumber)        
        buildContext: 'src/'
```