Eliminating hard-coded value from react website hosted on Azure
I have inherited some code for a website that is hosted on Azure. The code is written in TypeScript using the React framework. It is deployed to a Docker registry on Azure and a Web App then loads the Docker image and runs it.
The code uses msal-react for authentication. One of the values needed for Msal is the redirect URL (i.e., the base URL of the website), which is hardcoded as a const in one of the files. Whenever I want to modify the code and test it locally, I have to edit that file and change the value of redirectUri from its original value to http://localhost and then I have remember to undo that change before merging my code into the git branch and running the deployment pipeline.
I wonder if there is a way for me to avoid this. What I thought of was to store the base URL as an environment variable on the Web App itself (by editing its settings on Azure portal), and adding a logic in my code that checks if the environment variable is available, using that as the value for redirectUri and using http://localhost otherwise.
How can read the environment variable in the node.js web app code?

The way I solve this is roughly as follows:

When the docker container starts, I first run a small shell script that generates a configuration .json file (or .js file).
Load that file first (with fetch()) when your application loads.

The problem you have is that your React application builds when the docker container is created. So any dynamic (.env) values get baked into this build, and you don't want that. There are no environment variables in a browser.
So running a small script that builds a small config file cirmumvents this elegantly. If you really hate making an extra request, you could also embed the configuration in your index.html file somewhere.
If your docker container isn't just nginx with static files, but something like Node there's other options.

You can achieve this by adding a new application setting (example name) REACT_APP_REDIRECT_URI and set its value to the production redirect URL.
Then, modify your react code to check for the variable and use it if available.
// Initialize MSAL configuration to use environment variable.
// Included "|| 'http://localhost'" as fallback, for good coding practise.
const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: 'your-client-id',
        authority: 'your-authority-url',
        redirectUri: process.env.REACT_APP_REDIRECT_URI || 'http://localhost'; 
    }
};

Of course, ensure that you have a .env file in your root dir, with the variable:
REACT_APP_REDIRECT_URI=http://localhost

When you then build & deploy your project, it'll use the environment variable defined in your Azure Web App settings, and in local development, it'll use the .env file's value.
UPDATE:
Typically, environment variables defined in Azure web app should be passed to the Docker container already. So, I would first of all check that everywhere, the env variable has the same and correct name VITE_REACT_APP_REDIRECT_URI.
Check and ensure your Docker container has access to env variables. E.g., with Azure Cloud Shell:
docker exec -it your-container-id /bin/bash
echo $VITE_REACT_APP_REDIRECT_URI

If needed, you can modify the DockerFile, adding:
ENV VITE_REACT_APP_REDIRECT_URI=http://your-production-url

Note that the primary configuration should be managed through Azure Web App settings, and this should just be for testing.

Thanks for the quick response. I should have added that this web app uses Vite. When I tried process.env.REACT_APP_REDIRECT_URI  I get an error that process is not found. I changed that to import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_APP_REDIRECT_URI  per https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode and that seem to have done the trick.

This is working on my local environment, however, on Azure this is not picking up the environment variable. I have defined it on the Azure Web App, under Settings > Environment Variables. I modified my code to show the value it captures for import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_APP_REDIRECT_URI and on my local environment it shows it correctly, whereas on Azure it appears blank. Any ideas?

It may help to emphasize that locally, I run the app not through Docker, but on the Azure side, it is deployed via Docker. I think what is happening is the environment variable is not being passed from Azure Web App settings to the Docker container. Would appreciate ideas on how to solve for that.

@Merik Updated.

There are no environment variables in browser applications. There is no way this can work with build tools alone, unless you rebuild your entire application in docker every time you start. Something has be done at runtime.

Thanks. I also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59932994/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-dockerfile-via-azure-devops which corroborated what you said about the ENV command in the Dockerfile, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60287354/i-am-using-azure-devops-to-build-and-push-my-docker-image-how-can-i-pass-argume which showed me how to use pipeline variables to pass the value to Dockorfile as an argument. I ended up not using Web App Environment Variables, but rather put the redirect URL in the Build pipeline and pass it to the Dockerfile
